# "Cannot modify header information" warning?

Tags: wp-config, warnings

Problem I'm having:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /nfs/c06/h02/mnt/157520/domains/website/html/rpow/wp-config.php:1) in
>   /nfs/c06/h02/mnt/157520/domains/website/html/rpow/wp-includes/pluggable.php
>   on line 1207

I've tried to use FileZilla to find blank/invisible spaces and such in `index.php` and `wp-config.php`, I've tried to reinstall WordPress and replace `index.php` and `wp-config.php` with default files, I tried to resave files as `UTF-8`, but none of that worked. Is there anything that I haven't tried that might work? I can post both of my PHP files if necessary (I don't know where to upload them though).

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) you can read a very good discussion on the topic. Since this is the wp-config file, it could be that you have some whitespace before the `<?php` tag.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried turning off errors / warnings on your Server? Maybe no per `WP_DEBUG`, but rather some setting on your Servers admin interface.

Many times I encountered this error, it was caused by a Warning of some plugin.